# Calculating discrete probability distribution function for potentially infinite trials

Tags: probability, dice

I throw a die until the difference in value between successive trials is 1 (e.g 3 and 4 or 6 and 5). How do I calculate the pdf for the random variable n (number of trials?)  I can easily calculate for n equal to 2 or 3 but then the number of possibilities starts to get messy.

Comment: $$ \Pr(\text{difference}=1\mid\text{previous outcome}) = \begin{cases} 1/3 & \text{if previous}\in\{2,3,4,5\}, \\ 1/6 & \text{if previous}\in\{1,6\}. \end{cases} $$ So "success" on any trial is not independent of the previous outcome on the previous trial. However, I doubt that the way to solve this is by actual enumeration of sequences of outcomes.

Comment: Suppose you have a Markov chain with $36$ states: $\{ (i,j) : i,j\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\} \}.$ Then, for example, it's in state $(5,2),$ if those are the outcomes of two consecutive throws of the die, and it has probability $1/6$ of transitioning to any of the $6$ states $(2,j).$ The distribution of the initial state is determined by the first two throws of the die; subsequently just one more throw determines which state it is in next. You start measuring time with the second throw, not the first, but each throw thereafter corresponds to one unit of time. Then$\ldots \qquad$

Comment: $\ldots$you're looking for the probability distribution of the earliest time when it's in a state in which the two components of the pair differ by $1.$ So this is not about i.i.d. trials. $\qquad$

Comment: The random time $N$ is integer-valued and satisfies $N \in\{2, 3, 4, ...\}$.  It does not have a PDF, it has a PMF.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has symmetry $(1,2,3)\leftrightarrow(6,5,4)$. To exploit it, let us denote by $A_1$ the event that a roll is $1$ or $6$, $A_2$ the event that a roll is $2$ or $5$, $A_3$ the event that a roll is $3$ or $4$. After the first roll
\begin{align}
p_1^{(1)}=p_{A_1}^{(1)}=1/3\\
p_2^{(1)}=p_{A_2}^{(1)}=1/3\\
p_3^{(1)}=p_{A_3}^{(1)}=1/3
\end{align}
which we denote as column vector $P^{(1)}$.

Now we can think in terms of Markov chain with 4 states: the $A_1,A_2$ and $A_3$ state and absorbing state $A$. The transition matrix for the non-absorbing states is
\begin{equation}
T=\begin{pmatrix}
1/3&1/6&1/3\\
1/6&1/3&1/6\\
1/3&1/6&1/6
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

The probabilities of non-absorbing states after $n+1$ rolls is a vector
$$P^{(n+1)}=T^nP^{(1)}$$

Finally the probability of absorption after $n+1$ rolls (which is CDF of the distribution we are looking for) is

\begin{align}
P(X\leq n+1)
&=1-p_1^{(n+1)}-p_2^{(n+1)}-p_3^{(n+1)}\\
&=1-\sum_{i=1}^3\sum_{j=1}^3(T^n)_{i,j}P_j^{(1)}
\end{align}